# What kind of language does the following DFA accept?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

[image]

can anyone please describe the language this FA accepts? thank you

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style questions for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accept all the words containing $i$ "a"s and $j$ "b"s for which $i \equiv j \pmod{4}$.

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit? thank you.

Comment: It accepts strings like: ab, abba, bbbabb, aabaabaa but I can't seem to find a pattern.

Comment: Sure. Is there something in particular you are confused about? 
If you number the states clockwise from the initial state, counting from $0$ to $3$, then the $k$-th state represents all words with $i$ occurrences of the character "a" and $j$ occurrences of "b" such that $i \equiv j + k \pmod{4}$.
E.g., you'll end up in state 1 after reading one more "a" than "b" modulo $4$, e.g., "a", or "aab", "babaa", "aaabaaa", or "bbb"...
The accepted words (state 0) will have the same number of "a"s and "b"s modulo 4.

Comment: The concept of modular arithmetic has nothing special to do with FA. It was just a compact way to say that the number of "a"s minus the number of "b"s must be $0,4,8,12,...$ or $-4,-8,-12,...$.

Comment: oh okay. got it. thank you so much! :)